# error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-freeze

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

I was adding drawer navigation to my application and everything worked fine. But 4 days after I started receiving following error.

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-freeze from C:\Users\Jukez\Desktop\familyrecipebook\node_modules\react-native-screens\src\index.native.tsx: react-freeze could not be found within the project or in these directories
```

I have read the repository of the `react-native-screens` and tried adding the `enableFreeze(false)` to `App.js` but still the error remained. Then tried adding it to the `index.js` but the error still remained.

I have also run `yarn start --reset-cache` and `gradlew clean`

But those haven't worked either and now I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Re-install the package and after do "npm install".
If it doesnt work open your "package.json" file and remove the package from there.

Comment: I am using yarn instead npm. I have had lot of issues with npm in past.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was `react-native: 0.68.2` version and when downgraded to `0.68.1` everything worked normally. Seems like there is some issues within new version so have to wait little bit before updating